# mpv doesn't recognise ytdl_path as a key

Tags: linux, youtube-dl, mpv

I'm trying to use yt-dlp rather than youtube-dl due to the bottlenecking on download speeds in youtube-dl but I can't get it to work.

My mpv.conf file looks like:

`script-opts=ytdl_hook-ytdl_path=/usr/local/bin/yt-dlp`

When trying to get mpv to run I get this warning:

`[ytdl_hook] script-opts: unknown key ytdl_path, ignoring`

Does anyone know what the problem is? I've read through the mpv docs and it says this should work.

mpv is version 0.27.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, on mpv version 0.32.0.
The problem is that the ytdl-hook settings category is not an option in these older versions.
Your solutions are to update your mpv version or to create a link from youtube-dl to yt-dlp.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Now available [on Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/io.mpv.Mpv)

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to be a version issue. You could try to get the newest mpv version running (make sure you actually have lua support with it). That however can be a real pain.
A quicker solution is to just get rid of your old youtube-dl version and make a symbolic link called youtube-dl to your yt-dlp binary.